# Access Denied Calling a external website from CRM ribbon button click to open dialog

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, dynamics-crm-2013, same-origin-policy

I have a scenario where I have an external website hosted on my CRM Server, when trying to open this website with a URL using JavaScript I get an SCRIPT5: Access is denied error, I know this is related to the fact that my website is not in the same domain as CRM server, my external website is HTTPS hosted but different port and server as CRM, I cannot set my website to exatly as the CRM hosted serv3er as it will overridde it in IIS. How can I overcome this issue, please heklp, see my JS code below:

```
function PassOpgParameters(opgRoe,opgFactor,opgMargin,opgIdentifier) {

var Upload = "User OPG Upload";

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_name").setValue(Upload);
var roe = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_roe").getValue();
var factor = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_factor").getValue();
var margin = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_margin").getValue();

var opgID = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_opgid").getValue();

var encodeUrlParameter = "?data=" + encodeURIComponent('&opgRoe=roe&opgFactor=factor&opgMargin=margin&opgIdentifier=opgID');

 var url = "https://xxxxx.tarsus.co.za/" + encodeUrlParameter; //this url is different to CRM hosted server

var DialogOptions = new Xrm.DialogOptions();
DialogOptions.width = 540;
DialogOptions.height = 305;


Xrm.Internal.openDialog(url, DialogOptions, null, null, function (dialogResult) {
    if (dialogResult != null) {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_dialogresults").setValue(dialogResult);
        Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
    }
});
```

Comment: I see you're trying to adopt my suggested workaround. Is your target page really `*.tarsus.co.za/?data=` ? Are you sure there's no page name before your query parameters?

Comment: @Filburt my target page is  "https://xxx.tarsus.co.za" with xxx representing my IP/Server name